# Error al intentar instalar, por composer, un Service Provider en Laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel-5

He intentado con los siguientes:

> https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.3/html.

> https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables.

> https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar.

Con los 3 me arroja el mismo error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Actualización 1:**

Ahora me lanza este error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Como te recomendaron abajo verifica q version de php tenes. A partir de la version de laravel 5.3 te pide la ultima version de php5 o la 7. He tenido varios problemas de estos cuando empece en windows y me termine mudando a linux. Pero no basto y me termine instalando Homestead que si fue la solucion definitiva

Answer (score 1):

Primero verifica que versión de php tienes instalado, haciendo en consola 
`php -version` por otro lado también puedo notar que quizás te falte "phpunit" instalado, el cual te puedes bajar desde este sitio https://phpunit.de/ y también ejecuta en consola `php --ini` a ver que resultado te da